# The Role Manager feature has not been enabled. MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have that error when i update my database in package manager console  here's my configuration class and web config
The Role Manager feature has not been enabled.
please help me

MY CONFIGURATION CLASS

```
 namespace TechFactorsLMSV2.Migrations
 {
 using System;
 using System.Data.Entity;
 using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Web.Security;
 using TechFactorsLMSV2.Models;
 using WebMatrix.WebData;

internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<TechFactorsLMSV2.Models.LMSDBContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
    }

    protected override void Seed(TechFactorsLMSV2.Models.LMSDBContext context)
    {
        context.Schools.AddOrUpdate(d => d.SchoolName,
               new School() { SchoolName = "School 1" },
               new School() { SchoolName = "School 2" },
               new School() { SchoolName = "School 3" }
               );

        SeedMembership();
    }

    private void SeedMembership()
    {
        WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection",
            "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
        var roles = (SimpleRoleProvider)Roles.Provider;
        var membership = (SimpleMembershipProvider)Membership.Provider;

        if (!roles.RoleExists("Admin"))
        {
            roles.CreateRole("Admin");
        }
        if (membership.GetUser("kadadmin", false) == null)
        {
            membership.CreateUserAndAccount("kadadmin", "password");
        }
        if (!roles.GetRolesForUser("kadadmin").Contains("Admin"))
        {
            roles.AddUsersToRoles(new[] { "sallen" }, new[] { "admin" });
        }
    }
}
}
```

MY WEB CONFIG

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
<configSections>
<sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor"     type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
  <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
  <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
</sectionGroup>
 </configSections>
 <connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial    Catalog=aspnet-TechFactorsLMSV2;Integrated  Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\TechFactorsLMSV2.mdf"   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"  />
  </connectionStrings>

<system.web.webPages.razor>
<host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc,   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
<pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>



</system.web.webPages.razor>

<appSettings>
<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
</appSettings>



 <system.web>
 <httpHandlers>
  <add path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>
 </httpHandlers>

 <!--
    Enabling request validation in view pages would cause validation to occur
    after the input has already been processed by the controller. By default
    MVC performs request validation before a controller processes the input.
    To change this behavior apply the ValidateInputAttribute to a
    controller or action.
-->
<pages
    validateRequest="false"
    pageParserFilterType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewTypeParserFilter, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
    pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
    userControlBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
  <controls>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" namespace="System.Web.Mvc" tagPrefix="mvc" />
  </controls>
</pages>



<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="simple">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="simple" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleRoleProvider, 
                         WebMatrix.WebData"/>
  </providers>
</roleManager>
<membership defaultProvider="simple">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="simple" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider,
                         WebMatrix.WebData"/>
  </providers>
</membership>

</system.web>

<system.webServer>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />

<handlers>
  <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
  <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
</handlers>
```

Answer (score 10):

You need to add this to the web.config under system.web section

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="SimpleRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="SimpleRoleProvider" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleRoleProvider, WebMatrix.WebData"/>
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <membership defaultProvider="SimpleMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="SimpleMembershipProvider" 
             type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider, WebMatrix.WebData"/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
```

Comment: Now it says Could not load file or assembly 'WebMatrix.WebData' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Add a reference to the WebMatrix.WebData assembly

Comment: Look that CopyLocal is set to true.