# The Role Manager feature has not been enabled using Partial views

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, role-manager

I am currently trying to do the dynamic _Layout by reading the role that user currently logged is in adn i am having this error constantly.
Additional information: The Role Manager feature has not been enabled.
I know that it is because the roleManager was not enabled and i already tried the solution given in the similar topics but they seemed to not work for me (or i just messed up with them). I would be grateful if someone could help me.

Here is my code that throws an exception:

http://pastebin.com/3FnrSxCy
And i use it like this:

```
@Html.Partial("_Menu")
```

And here is my web.config file:
http://pastebin.com/zSH6hMnZ

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not putted your role manager configuration in web.config. - Try something like following link.

[The Role Manager feature has not been enabled. MVC 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15331488/the-role-manager-feature-has-not-been-enabled-mvc-4)

Comment: http://scr.hu/11m6/0onxu
This is what i get after i tried it. And yes i've added reference to webmatrix.webdata

Comment: this was just a example. You need to implement your own role provider that you have written